# Storing user settings in table - how?

Tags: database, schema, settings

I have about 200 settings for the user. These include notice settings and tracking settings from user activities on objects. The problem is how to store it in the DB? Should each setting be a row or a column? If column then table will have 200 colunms. If row then about 3 colunms but 200 rows per user x even 10 million users = not good.

So how else can I store all these settings?

These settings are a mix of text entry and FK lookups to other tables.

Comment: If you don't need to search on some field, you can serialize and store them all in one text field. For me, creating a column per field is OK. To improve search/selection, you could split them in several tables like user_profile, user_inteface_settings, user_... (tables that can be used indepently). -- Creating a generic table that contains settings : one per row like (uid, field, value) is useful if you have a lot of optional fields and could result to a 200 * 10 000 000 = 2 000 000 000 rows's table.

Comment: Mdillion - just to remind you, you should 'accept' the answer that helped you the most.

Comment: My problem is still not solved. There are so many settings and both ways mentioned here are not working properly. So I am exploring some other options and once I find something I'll accept the closest answer.

Comment: @MathiasE. 
```you could split them in several tables like user_profile, user_inteface_settings, user_... (tables that can be used indepently)``` isnt this a one-to-one realtionship? between the user table and all the settings table? since the user will own each row in the other tables and the different columns get updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That you have 200 settings to track suggests a flexible database schema. As such I'd suggest a hybrid approach:

1. **Users**: table with row per user for properties that a user will likely always have, such as username and password. This table may also keep foreign keys, but this is a heuristic and also depends if the relationship is zero-to-1 or zero-to-many. Where the latter requires a separate table.
2. **Features**: two options

   1. table with row per feature, effectively a hashtable, with userId, name and value columns. This could also be a spot for foreign relationships, but you would not be able to enforce data integrity in this setup.
   2. XML, but only with a database that has features that allow you to query the data or only for data that you do not need to query, but only work with on your application server.

I think the bigger answer is you are not going to arrive at one solution from your original question, but instead need to use both to suit the data.

Comment: what is the read time if the table has say 10 millions rows and needs to find 200 settings for a user to load the settings page? Will the user see the page instant or will it take like a minute to lookup and load the user page?

Comment: With the right indices, read time should be good. That noted, I'd suggest loading information once at login as part of the user's session instead of repeat database trips every time a permission needs checking.

Answer (score 5):

Serializing the data almost always turns out to be a bad idea, because in doing so you cripple the dbms. All of the man years that went into producing an efficient dbms will be wasted on a serialized bucket of bits.

If you have application logic hooked up against each setting, I think you should implement it as either:

**1 column per setting in the settings table.**
This makes it easier to leverage the power of your dbms, with constraint checking, referential integrity, correct data type for your values, plenty of information to the optimizer. The downside is that row size grows.

or

**1 table per setting (or group of related settings).**
This has all of the benefits of the above, but trades rowsize for a performance penalty when you need to fetch most or all of the settings at once. When settings are optional, this alternative will be significantly smaller if the actual data is sparse.

Also, lots of columns is often a "smell", that suggests you haven't normalized your data correctly, but it doesn't have to be that way. Only you know your data.

Comment: Lot of colums are because of "privacy levels per user activity". Each user activity has a user defined privacy level an a default system defined privacy level. For system setting it is fine but user settins get out of hand when we have 200 activities each with its own setting.

Answer (score 2):

I think 200 columns is definitely not good idea, because of difficulty in writing stored procs, manually viewing data or extending to more settings later.

Can you try XML for all these 200 settings and then you will have only 1 row per user. username and corresponding settings xml. But again it will limit your querying capabilities, but DBs now support XML. You can specifically check out XML DBs.

Comment: I am not sure of entire details, but it can be done.  Read this: http://www.stylusstudio.com/xsllist/200205/post70200.html                                                 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345117(v=sql.90).aspx